# name 'login' is not defined. python (django)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have one problem, w want create user and after login. i create user but can't login. my error ---> **name 'login' is not defined**. from django.contrib.auth.views import login. I tried this too but it didn't work

where do I have a problem and how can it be resolved? i couldn't find a way to solve the problem on Google. 
please help me, Thanks in advance.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import  HttpResponse
import datetime
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from home.forms import SignUp

def regform(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUp(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = SignUp()
    return render(request, 'home/home.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django import forms


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    mob = models.IntegerField(default=None) 


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import password_validation
from django.db import models


from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class SignUp(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user



    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields=("email", 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name','mob')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the error is clear, login is not defined. What's the error when importing it? Maybe you were missing passing the request, or the import was wrong.

Try this, from [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in):

```
...
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
...

def regform(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUp(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ...
            user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            ...
```

Comment: Glad to help! -